Citext and unaccent field in Java Postgresql
I have a field that I want to handle as unaccented and case-insensitive.
I have a migration script which creates an extension for CITEXT:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS CITEXT;

I also have a script to alter the table type to CITEXT:
ALTER TABLE public.capabilities_group
  ALTER COLUMN name TYPE CITEXT;

The functionality was verified with the line below:
predicates.add(builder.like(capabilitiesGroupJoin.get(searchBy.toLowerCase()), "%" + searchValue + "%"));

I want to expand on this to now handle unaccented values as well. I have done the same for UNACCENT below and expanded the code:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS UNACCENT;

Join<AccountCapabilitiesGroups, CapabilitiesGroup> capabilitiesGroupJoin = root.join("capabilitiesGroup", JoinType.INNER);
predicates.add(builder.like(builder.function("unaccent", String.class, capabilitiesGroupJoin.get(searchBy.toLowerCase())), "%" + searchValue + "%"));

This now seems to handle unaccented but has lost the CITEXT handling.
How can I preserve both CITEXT and Unaccented using Java Spring w/ JPA
Do I need to alter the table field somehow?
